# Azure DNSについて

Tags: azure, dns

Azure DNSについて、ご存じであれば教えてください。
現在、レジストラでドメインを購入し、それをAzure DNSに委任することを考えております。
そのとき、サブドメインのレコードを作成できるのは確認したのですが、
購入したドメイン名そのままを使用するレコードは作成できないのでしょうか。
以下に例を記載します。

例:
example.comをレジストラで購入し、以下の3つのCNAMEレコードを作成したい。
(1) 「example.com」を「test1.trafficmanager.net」に解決
(2) 「maint.example.com」を「test1.trafficmanager.net:7000」に解決
(3) 「web.example.com」を「test2.trafficmanager.net」に解決

(2)と(3)が可能なことは実際に確認しましたが、(1)を実現する方法がわかりません。

レジストラで購入した「example.com」がそのまま使えるようなレコードを記述する方法はないのでしょうか。

ご存じの方がいましたら教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: タイトルに質問の内容を反映して下さい

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (1) 「example.com」を「test1.trafficmanager.net」に解決

ドメイン名そのものには CNAME は 作成できませんので実現不可能だと思います。

回避方法は、「example.com」への接続を、サーバー上で強制的に別の サブドメイン にリダイレクトさせ trafficmanager.net にトラフィックが向かうようにする事が出来ます。

シナリオ：
・クライアントが「example.com」にアクセス
・example.comの Webサーバーが「www.example.com」へのリダイレクトを返す
・クライアントが「www.example.com」の名前を正引き
・DNSが test1.trafficmanager.net の CNAME を返す
・クライアントが「test1.trafficmanager.net」の名前を正引き
・DNSが TraficmanagerのIPアドレスを返す
・クライアントは Traficmanager のIPにアクセス

FAQにも同じようなことが書かれてましたが、開発待ちの機能だそうです。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs

> この問題を回避するために、HTTP リダイレクトを使用してトラフィックをネイキッド ドメイン名から別の URL に転送することをお勧めします。これにより、Traffic Manager を使用できるようになります。 たとえば、ネイキッド ドメイン "contoso.com" を使用すると、Traffic Manager の DNS 名を指す CNAME "www.contoso.com" にユーザーをリダイレクトできます。
>
> Traffic Manager におけるネイキッド ドメインの完全サポートは、開発待ちの機能として登録されています。 この機能を要求するためにサポートを登録するには、コミュニティ フィードバック サイトの投票で、ぜひ支持を表明してください。